# Hive query equivalent of sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql, hdfs

Hi I have a table student as follows:

```
student_id course_id
1111       100
2222       101
3333       101
4444       102
5555       103
```

And a courses table as follows:

```
course_id course_desc
100       Electronics
101       Computer
102       Mechanical
```

In case If I want to join the above 2 tables I have course_id from student table which is not listed in courses table. So every time I do join I should compare the course_id with courses table and come to know a new course_id is in students table.

I believe in Sql we can use such as :

```
select DISTINCT course_id from students WHERE course_id NOT IN ( select course_id FROM courses);
```

How this can be done in Hive, any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select students.course_id from students students LEFT OUTER JOIN courses courses  ON (students.course_id = courses.course_id) where courses.course_id is null;
```

I don't think NOT IN is supported so this work around.